# Looping through a dataobject with a $has_many relationship?

Tags: silverstripe

I have a `$has_many` relation on my `DashboardPage` to my `PastEvent` dataobject. In my DashboardPage.ss template I want to be able to loop through all the `PastEvents`. I believe because of the **$has_many** relationship I should be able to do the following on the `DashboardPage.ss` template:

**DashboardPage.ss**

```
<% loop $PastEvents %>
    <div>
      <div>$EventName</div>
      <div>$ClassType</div>
      etc...
   </div>
<% end_loop %>
```

However nothing is showing. What am I missing?

**DashboardPage.php**

```
<?php

class DashboardPage extends Page implements TemplateGlobalProvider {

    private static $db = array(
        'Testing' => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    private static $has_many = array(
        'PastEvents' => 'PastEvent'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->removeByName('Content');

        return $fields;
    }

    public static function get_template_global_variables() {
        return array('DashboardLink' => 'getDashboardLink');
    }

    public static function getDashboardLink($action='') {
        $page = DashboardPage::get()->first();
        return $page ? $page->Link($action) : '';
    }

}

class DashboardPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'show'
    );


    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        Requirements::css('themes/' . SSViewer::current_theme() . '/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css');
        Requirements::css('themes/' . SSViewer::current_theme() . '/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css');
        Requirements::css('themes/' . SSViewer::current_theme() . '/owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css');
    }

    public function show(){
        dd('Coming here');
    }

}
```

**PastEvent.php**

```
<?php

class PastEvent extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'EventName' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'ClassType' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'Instructor' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'EmbedCode' => 'Text',
        'EventDate' => 'Date',
        'Time' => 'Time'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'BranchLocation' => 'BranchLocation',
        'DashboardPage' => 'DashboardPage'
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'EventName' => 'EventName',
        'BranchLocation.Name' => 'Branch Location',
        'ClassType' => 'ClassType',
        'Instructor' => 'Instructor',
        'EventDate' => 'Event Date',
        'Time' => 'Time',
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = new FieldList(
            TextField::create('EventName'),
            TextField::create('ClassType'),
            TextField::create('Instructor'),
            DropdownField::create(
                'BranchLocationID',
                'Branch Location',
                BranchLocation::get()->map('ID', 'Name')->toArray()
            ),
            TextareaField::create('EmbedCode'),
            DateField::create('EventDate')->setConfig('showcalendar', true)->setDescription('Click inside textbox to open calender'),
            TimePickerField::create('Time')
        );

        return $fields;
    }

    public function Link() {
        return $this->DashboardPage()->Link('show/'.$this->ID);
    }

}
```

Comment: ifusion, how are you setting the relation between the DashboardPage and the PastEvent?

Comment: @muskie9 - There is s $has_one on the PastEvent Object to the DashboardPage and a $has_many on the DashboardPage `$PastEvents => $PastEvent`

Comment: @ifusion where do you add `PastEvent`s to `DashboardPage` to decide what `PastEvent`s are related to `DashboardPage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manage PastEvent on the DashboardPage

```
public function getCMSFields() {
...
    $fields->push(GridField::create('PastEvents', 'Past Events',
        $this->PastEvents(),
        singleton('PastEvent')->canEdit()
            ? GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
            : GridFieldConfig_RecordViewer::create()
    ));
...
}
```

You can add past events from another place, assuming that you created your page with '/dashboard' url.

```
$dashboard = SiteTree::get_by_link('dashboard');
$events = $dashboard->PastEvents();
$events->add($this->createNewEvent());
```

You don't need your `show()` action to display the DashboardPage (implicit `index()` action is used by default). Page actions extend page url, so your action will be called when you request `/dashboard/show`, that seems is your intention.

Improve your template to show that there are no events:

```
<% if $PastEvents.Count %>
    <ul>
    <% loop $PastEvents %>
        <li>
            <a href="$Link">$EventName</a>
            <div>$ClassType</div>
            ...
        </li>
    <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
<% else %>
    <p>There are no past events.</p>
<% end_if %>
```

Since your page provides proper link to `show` action

```
public function Link() {
    return $this->DashboardPage()->Link('show/'.$this->ID);
}
```

Your show action might be like this

```
public function show($eventID = 0) {
    $event = $this->PastEvents()->byID($eventID);
    if (!$event) {
        $this->httpError(404);
    }

    // render with templates/Page.ss and templates/Layout/PastEventDetails.ss
    return $event->renderWith(array('PastEventDetails', 'Page'));
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for your help :) Got it working now. I was trying to create a dataobject as a page for the PastEvents (sorry should have put that in my question). Thats why I had the Link() method on the PastEvents dataobject. I was following this tutorial:https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/controller-actions-dataobjects-as-pages - I just changed the names e.g RegionsPage.php = DashboardPage.php and Region.php = PastEvent.php